# How to solve multi-project build problems in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, maven, gradle, intellij-idea

When opening directories that contain multiple Java projects with IntelliJ IDEA I regularly encounter build problems that cannot be solved with the built-in mechanisms (build tool reload or *Invalidate Caches* menu item). They typically occur after structural changes like refactoring or changing dependencies, both with Maven and Gradle as the build tools.

The effect of the problem is that new or changed dependencies are not recognized or that some projects in the monorepo are no longer recognized by IDEA. In the case of library projects that will cause build errors in all dependent projects.

I have found a manual fix for this which I will provide as my own answer but maybe someone can provide a better solution.

Comment: Simply remove the `.idea` directory completely and import the project new...

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help in these cases because the build system cache is still there.

Comment: Addition: deleting `.idea` works sometimes (it was actually the first workaround I used), but not consistently. The solution I provided in my answer so far always worked but is annoying as it is necessary to exit IDEA and then let the build tool re-scan the whole project. But deleting `.idea` is even more annoying because you loose all your settings too.

Comment: What kind of settings do you have? Everything I need is in my pom file...

Comment: As mentioned in my comment below, there is no global POM. The base directory is just a directory containing multiple projects (a Git monorepo).

Comment: Hm.. Ok...might be worth to consider to introduce one a solve that problem.. ?

Comment: Does **Reload** action not helpful after you changed the dependencies? Does the **Reload** complete successfully but you still get build errors after this?

Comment: @khmarbaise: global build makes no sense as the projects in a monorepo are not all related.

Comment: @Andrey: as mentioned, reload won't help.

Comment: Does the **Reload** complete successfully?

Comment: I suggest you to file an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with IDE logs attached (using Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data action) after this happens.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution to this is to manually delete IDEAs build tool cache. To do so first quit IDEA, than delete the corresponding project directory (named .) from the following location (I recommend to backup first):

On Unix: `~/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea<idea-version>/external_build_system`

On Windows: `<user-home>\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea<idea-version>\external_build_system`

On Mac OS: `~/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea<idea-version>/external_build_system`

When restarting IDEA it should re-scan the project correctly. At least in my case this has always worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

This offtenly works for me:

1 In master project pom I just commenting lines which defines submodules.

2 Then I'm waiting when IDEA will suggest to exclude subprojects.
After this action submodule directories will be displayed just like some external file directories, not like a project.

3 Then I uncomment the lines in pom and wait when IDEA will add subprojects again.

4 After this action I select rebuild project in Build section and it works.

I've tested this with maven projects, hope should work for gradle too.

---

But I agree, sometimes we have to combine this with invalidating caches or just project reopen, or deleting .idea directories.

Comment: In my case there is no master project. The projects are just in the same parent folder as it's a Git monorepo but the parent has no build definitions. IDEA therefore needs to scan each sub-project separately which works fine initially but fails on the mentioned structural changes.